# How to get random edge seams to maximise texture space from a flat surface with lots of holes in it?

Tags: python, texturing, uv, add-on

I'd like to be able to automatically break an object UV randomly (following a noise pattern would be the best way to do it I guess). Smart UV project does that, but only based on angle. Therefore if an object is completely (or mostly) flat you'll get giant UV islands, which are bad if there is a lot of holes in your mesh.

Let me illustrate, this is the result of a Smart UV project on a place with holes in it:
[image]

And this is the result when I manually select seams:
[image]

As you can see the second result is much better regarding texture space usage. Note that I really don't care which edge is a seam and which is not, as long as the UV is broken into multiple parts since I'll be manually painting it in Texture paint mode. Therefore I have no need to do my seams intelligently.

I've had OK results using random selection in edge mode followed by edge loop selection, but it's really not that great, this is the result:

[image]

Now for the question. Is there an addon or a way to have some kind of voronoi noise do the seams for me?

For example by projecting this texture from view onto my mesh, and somehow have some continuity in the edge seams by selecting the one adjacent to the black lines:
[image]

I'd just need to be able to control the scale of the noise, so I don't end up with too big or too small islands.